# Microsoft Word Mac, Remove the L Headers

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

How do I get rid of these header `L` marks in Microsoft Word Mac?  They probably are related to header marks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I get rid of this header L marks in Microsoft Word Mac?

They are "Crop Marks".

To remove them:

File > Options > Advanced > Show document content > Uncheck Show crop marks > Press OK

> [image]

Source: [How to quickly show or hide crop marks in Word?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/943-word-show-hide-crop-marks.html#a1)

Answer (score 2):

On the current version of Word on MacOS Ventura

1. click *Word*->*Settings...* (On earlier versions of MacOS(X) this would be *Word*->*Preferences...* )

[image: Click Word->Settings...]

2. Click the *View* icon

[image: Click the View icon]

3. Uncheck the *Crop Marks* box

[image: Uncheck the Crop Marks box]